# toDoList with localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have to do a simple todo app with local storage. I've done this app that works but without local storage. 
How can i add a localStorage in my todoList? I mean that if i refresh the page, my todoList is saved automatically. I can't do it. if anyone can help me, i would really appreciate it.

```
var todoList = [];
function addTodo(frm)
{
    var todo = frm.txtTodo;
    if(todo.value != "")
    {
        todoList.push({"title":todo.value,"status":1});
        todo.value="";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("you have to write something!");
        return false;
    }

    todo.focus();


    displayTodoItems();
    return false;
}

function todoAction(no,action)
{
    if(no != null)
    {
        todoList[no].status = action;
    }
    displayTodoItems();
}

function todoDelete(no)
{
    todoList.splice(no,1);
    displayTodoItems();
}

function displayTodoItems(){
    var contStart = "<ul>";
    var listItems = "";
    var contEnd = "</ul>";

    if(todoList.length > 0)
    {
        for(var i=0; i < todoList.length; i++)
        {
            var actionClass = todoList[i].status==0?"Done":"Not done";  
            var setStatus =  todoList[i].status==0?1:0;
            listItems+= "<li class='"+actionClass+"'><span class='title'>"+todoList[i].title+"</span>"
            listItems+= "<span class='action'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='todoAction("+i+","+setStatus+");'>";
            listItems+= todoList[i].status==0?"Not done":"Done";
            listItems+= "</a> <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='todoDelete("+i+");'> X </a>";
            listItems+="</span></li>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listItems+= "<li><span class='title'>There are not tasks!</span></li>";
    }



    document.getElementById("todoList").innerHTML = contStart+listItems+contEnd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to create To-do list using local storage:

The following code with not work in stack overflow due to security concern do try at your system.

```js
(function(){
  
  var list = document.querySelector('#list'),
      form = document.querySelector('form'),
      item = document.querySelector('#item');
  
  form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    list.innerHTML += '<li>' + item.value + '</li>';
    store();
    item.value = "";
  },false)
  
  list.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var t = e.target;
    if(t.classList.contains('checked')){
      t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
    } else {
      t.classList.add('checked');
    }
    store();
  },false)
  
  function store() {
    window.localStorage.myitems = list.innerHTML;
  }
  
  function getValues() {
    var storedValues = window.localStorage.myitems;
    if(!storedValues) {
      list.innerHTML = '<li>Make a to do list</li>'+
                       '<li>Check off first thing on the to do list</li>'+
                       '<li>Realize you have already accomplished 2 things in the list</li>'+
                       '<li>Reward yourself with a nap</li>';
    }
    else {
      list.innerHTML = storedValues;
    }
  }
  getValues();
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #cfcbcc;
}

input {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 98.4%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcbcc;
  outline: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
}

h2 {
  color: gray;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    color: #899098;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcbcc;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 8px 0;
    &:before {
      content: "\25A1";
      padding: 10px 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: line-through;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
  }
}

.checked {
  color: green;
  &:before {
    content: "\2713";
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    &:after {
      content: "(remove)";
      color: tomato;
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<div class="container">

  <form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item" placeholder="Add New" />
  </form>
  <ul id="list"></ul>

</div>
```